# Why is enumerate empty when passed a non-empty iterable?

Tags: python

It's my understanding that the `enumerate()` function will loop over each item in an iterable. However, in the example below is does not loop at all when given a non-empty iterable.

```
import itertools
x = itertools.chain(
    itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 1),
    itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2),
    itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 3),
)
print(list(x))
print(list(enumerate(x)))
print(list(enumerate(list(x))))
print(list(enumerate([(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)])))
```

Output:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
[]
[]
[(0, (1,)), (1, (2,)), (2, (3,)), (3, (1, 2)), (4, (1, 3)), (5, (2, 3)), (6, (1, 2, 3))]
```

Expected output:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
[(0, (1,)), (1, (2,)), (2, (3,)), (3, (1, 2)), (4, (1, 3)), (5, (2, 3)), (6, (1, 2, 3))]
[(0, (1,)), (1, (2,)), (2, (3,)), (3, (1, 2)), (4, (1, 3)), (5, (2, 3)), (6, (1, 2, 3))]
[(0, (1,)), (1, (2,)), (2, (3,)), (3, (1, 2)), (4, (1, 3)), (5, (2, 3)), (6, (1, 2, 3))]
```

I'm running this with Python 3.8.2 on Arch Linux.

Can someone explain why `enumerate()` does not loop with these inputs?

Comment: `x` wasn't empty at first, but it's empty by the time `enumerate` sees it.

Answer (score 1):

You exhausted your chained iterator with the first `print` statement.  The second and third *did* receive an empty iterator.  If you want to see *your* expected output, you need to rebuild the chain for each run-through.

This is not specific to `chain`, nor to `enumerate`; you can get the same effect with

```
x = iter(range(10))
```

Comment: `range` isn't an iterator, so that particular example doesn't fit.

Comment: make it x = iter(range(10)) for it to show the currently desired behaviour.